# Cannot get external images in NextJS with Custom server Express

Tags: express, next.js, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-resource-policy

I'm developing NextJS app with custom server by ExpressJS, and the app cannot show external image, code example:

```
export function DocumentSection({content}) {
  return (
    <section className={styles.documentSection}>
      <div className={`${styles.container} container`}>
        <div className={styles.docNav}>

        </div>
        <img src='https://https://abc.xyz/example.png'/>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Error:
"GET https://abc.xyz/example.png net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200"

Everything work normally if I using only `next dev`

Answer (score 0):

if you have `helmet` middleware on the server you should remove it or rather use these simple configuration.

```
server.use(helmet.crossOriginOpenerPolicy());
server.use(helmet.dnsPrefetchControl());
server.use(helmet.expectCt());
server.use(helmet.frameguard());
server.use(helmet.hsts());
server.use(helmet.ieNoOpen());
server.use(helmet.noSniff());
server.use(helmet.originAgentCluster());
server.use(helmet.permittedCrossDomainPolicies());
server.use(helmet.referrerPolicy());
server.use(helmet.xssFilter());
server.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy())
```